# Why does a custom android view not take a TypedArray as a argument

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-custom-attributes

I am learning to write custom view in Android, and reading the documentation.

A custom view is passed an AttributeSet as a parameter. But the documentation says to get a TypedArray using the following code

```
TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
        attrs,
        R.styleable.PieChart,
        0, 0);
```

So why doesn't it just pass a TypedArray to begin with? When would you want to inspect the AttributeSet instead?

The documentation specifies that you do not want to inspect the raw AttributeSet because...

> -Resource references within attribute values are not resolved

Wha?? Does this mean if I have a custom attribute x=10 in xml, that it will not equal 10 until it is resolved?

> -Styles are not applied

If I have a custom attribute in xml x=10, what would applying a style do it actually do?

Comment: it means that reading `AttributeSet ` directly returns "raw" data passed in xml: for example if you have `android:background="@drawable/some_drawable"` you will get the raw string `@drawable/some_drawable"` and not the `Drawable` class instance

Comment: Ahhh ok that makes sense! Still, I think it would make more sense to pass the typed array. Android is such excessively verbose code.

Comment: no one can pass `TypedArray` as you can pass different params to `obtainStyledAttributes`: you passed two zeroes as the last two params but it is not always the case, also how would system guess `R.styleable.PieChart`?

Comment: Ya my problem is that I don't get stylables I guess. I thought if I instantiate a PieChart in xml, the PieChart constructor would get those attributes passed to it.

Comment: but now you have TypedArray already,  so what's the problem?

Comment: I was going to answer this question, but as you already have, @pskink, maybe you want to convert your own comments to an answer form